# Ext JS - Creating same grid multiple times is not working

Tags: extjs, extjs4, multiple-instances

I have defined a new class "ConfirmationPanel" and I want to create this panel inside the window. It shows up fine when I create the window first time. But when I create the second window, the panel in window-1 moves to window-2. I want to have the same panel created twice for each window. How can I do that?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.views.ConfirmationPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    requires: 'MyApp.store.ConfirmationStore',
    border: false,
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.ConfirmationStore', {});
        this.columns = this.buildColumns();
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    buildColumns: function() {
        return [
            {text: "Id", width: 50, flex: 1, dataIndex: 'docId', sortable: true},
            {text: "Name", width: 150, dataIndex: 'docName', sortable: true},
            {text: "Type", width: 75, dataIndex: 'docType', sortable: true},
            {text: "URL", width: 115, dataIndex: 'docUrl', sortable: true},
            {text: "Sent Time", width: 115, dataIndex: 'docSentTime', sortable: true},
            {text: "Ack Time", width: 115, dataIndex: 'docAckTime', sortable: true}
        ];
    },
    viewConfig: {
        listeners: {
            itemdblclick: function( dataview, record, item, index, e) {
                alert( 'opening document here');
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Any help/advice is appreciated.

---- I tried to create new instance of panel as below inside tabpanel. But even then it created only one instance. May be I am doing something basically wrong.

```
    items: {
        xtype:'tabpanel',
        plain:true,
        activeTab: 0,
        height:350,
        defaults:{
            bodyPadding: 10 
        },
        items: [
            {
                title:'Test',
                items: Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                    bodyPadding: 5,  
                    title: 'Filters',
                    items: [{
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'Start date'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: 'End date'
                    }]
                })

            },
            {
                title:'My Confirms',
                items: Ext.create( "MyApp.views.ConfirmationPanel")
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me how you are creating the second instance of ConfirmationPanel?

Comment: Could you share more code? Especially a place where you create a new window. Sometimes I saw similar issues, when two components get the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Ext.define('MyApp.views.ConfirmationPanel', {
    ...
    alias: 'confirmpanel',
    ...
```

and inside tabpanel:

```
        {
            title:'My Confirms',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'confirmpanel'
            }]
        }
```

the reason of such a behaviour that you get is because the only one instance of MyApp.views.ConfirmationPanel is created during your setup via Ext.create( "MyApp.views.ConfirmationPanel")